# SSIS precedence constraint OR for child task to continue when one of parent task completes

Tags: ssis

I have 2 tasks (task 1, task 2) that run in parallel. The success arrow of both tasks is pointed to task 3.

So task 3 runs only when task 1 and 2 complete successfully.

Is there any way that task 3 can be made to run when either of task 1 or task 2 completes?

Comment: Yes. If you double click the arrow you can change it to OR

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an old package I was working on : the value of multiple constraint property-Logical OR– One constraint must evaluate to True:
[image]
you can note the changes in SSIS precedence constraints lines. It changes lines from solid to dotted lines:
[image]

Execute the SSIS package, and we can see the following:

- Execute SQL task 1 status is a success
- Execute SQL task 3 status is fail
- Logical OR of these two precedence constraints returns true, and it
  executes SQL task 2

[image]

Comment: @variable yes both